# "select2" Add constant option

Tags: jquery-select2, jquery-select2-4

I am currently using Select2 in a project and would like to add a option to my select list that shows up regardless of what the user types or searches. The idea is to have a "Add new" option always present in the list.
I do not think my code is necessary here (but if needed I may provide) as the only thing i'm lacking knowledge in this specific topic is on how to keed the option always showing.
I thought of using the matcher attribute, but i'm not sure how.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to do it setting a new matcher, the problem was I was not sure on how to create a new matcher and still use the select2 default one.
Something else I was missing was the full version of select2.

```js
function newMatcher(term, text){
    //The "ADD NEW" String is the text in the option I want to always show up.
    //The code after OR looks for the actual results for the user's search
    if ((text.toUpperCase().indexOf("ADD NEW") > -1)
       || (text.toUpperCase().indexOf(term.toUpperCase()) > -1)) {
         return true;
    }
}
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.fn.select2.amd.require(['select2/compat/matcher'], function (oldMatcher) {
        $('select').select2({
            matcher: oldMatcher(newMatcher)
        })
    })
});
```